# How to Add a Window in ConsoleApplication Project C++

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

Hi i Want to Add Window(Gui) to my ConsoleApplication in C++
How to do this?? I need something called Hwnd? I tried to use it and it does not work for me

Basically what I want to do is a MessageBox that will be every time somewhere else on the screen .. but I realized that you have to do it with HWND.

I need Tutorial How to create windows with hwnd

I try:

```
HWND GetWindow(HWND hWnd, UINT uCmd);
```

Comment: _I tried to use it and it does not work for me_: So what did not work? Was the dialog not displayed? Did it format your hard drive? Did it set your house on fire? Show your code. You can [edit]  your question.

Comment: For Winapi `MessageBox` specifically, you can just drop HWND and use NULL instead. It tells Windows who owns the MessageBox. If you use NULL, nobody owns it.

Comment: `HWND GetWindow(HWND hWnd, UINT uCmd);` this is just a declaration. You need to show _your_ failing code. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: How to do This?

Comment: I dont Now How to Work With Hwnd...

Comment: Hi Progremmer, does the answer solve your issue? Please let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following code meet your requirement:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Hello World!"), TEXT("Message"), MB_TOPMOST);
}
```

It will like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You've used multiple tags, I have a winapi solution, not a winforms one.

You can use a std. MessageBox by calling the function, but they can't be „evolved“ into your custom windows for any reasonable „price“ so they can only notify user and ask simple yes/no questions. For „real“ windows, let's forget MessageBox.

The simplest custom window is a std. windows Dialog. It uses the pre-defined window class #32770, so you don't have to register your window class, create a message loop etc. The simplest way to open it is DialogBoxParam function. You must make a .rc dialog script (there are lots of visual editors), compile it with a resource compiler, link into your .exe and pass it's name as the parameter for DialogBoxParam.

Here's an example of a window inside a console application (C++ part only), using this DialogBoxParam call

```
DialogBoxParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL),"EXAMPLE",NULL,ExampleWindowFunction,NULL);
```

It's here: https://pastebin.com/Crkdy5FB

It also contains image drawing (you probably don't need it yet, it's left from another winapi example). Use it as a sandbox, you'll probably quickly understand how it works and what role the hWnd plays here.

I understand your problems. GUI got so overcomplicated so it's hard to understand what exactly you don't understand. It prevents from asking a good question.

Comment: How can this help? This is merely a comment.

Comment: Sorry, some odd things happen when I try to add a link to Pastebin. Addedd a meaningless line of code and it's posted now.

Comment: Re-worked the answer. I don't however understand yet why pastebin links must come with „code“ formatting and how exactly they should be connected together.